# have to submit form twice to get data from second api request but only want to submit once

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

at the current state when submitting the form it will display the data from the first api but then to display the data from the second api which needs an id from the first api you need to submit the form again with the same input.

```
const onFormSubmit = async (searchItem) => {
    await getFirstAPI(searchItem);
    await getSecondAPI(playerId);
  };

  const getFirstAPI = async (searchItem) => {
    const res = await axios
      .get(
        "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" +
          searchItem +
          "?api_key=" +
          APIKEY
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setHaveData(true);
        setPuuid(res.data.puuid);
        setPlayerId(res.data.id);
        setPlayerImage(res.data.profileIconId + ".png");
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };

  const getSecondAPI = async (playerId) => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/entries/by-summoner/" +
        playerId +
        "?api_key=" +
        APIKEY
    );
    setPlayerStats(res.data[0]);
    console.log(playerStats);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either return the new `playerId` from the first API:

```
const onFormSubmit = async (searchItem) => {
    const updatedPlayerId = await getFirstAPI(searchItem);
    await getSecondAPI(updatedPlayerId);
};

const getFirstAPI = async (searchItem) => {
    const res = await axios
        .get(
            "https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" +
            searchItem +
            "?api_key=" +
            APIKEY
        )
        .then((res) => {
            setHaveData(true);
            setPuuid(res.data.puuid);
            setPlayerId(res.data.id);
            setPlayerImage(res.data.profileIconId + ".png");
            console.log(res.data);
            return updatedPlayerId;
        });
};
```

Or use an effect hook that runs the second API when one of the states that gets set changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (playerId) {
    getSecondAPI(playerId)
    // .catch(handleErrors);
  }
}, [playerId]);
```